# I need to create the dependent drop down list for same columns in same row

Tags: php, html, ajax, yii

i need ur help..i am creating a web application  about books entry using yii.
in a form i need to dropdown a isbn number from one table that should retrieve the relavive book title which is in the same row in another text field or dropdown box....i hope u understand my prob please give suggestion.here is my coding for html view page

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'isbn_no'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'isbn_no',CHtml::listData(Books::model()->findAll(array('order'=> 'isbn_no ASC')),                            'isbn_no', 'isbn_no'),array('empty'=>'Select'),array(
                    'ajax' => array(
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'url' => CController::createUrl('Processcontroller/Book'),
                    'update' => "#book_title"
                )));?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'isbn_no'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'book_title'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'book_title','',array(),array('empty'=>'select'));

    <?php echo $form->error($model,'book_title'); ?>
</div>
```

my controller named ProcessController.php

```
public function actionBook()
{
//please enter current controller name because yii send multi dim array
    $data=Books::model()->findAll('book_id=:book_id', 
                  array(':book_id'=> $_POST['current-Controller']['book_id']));

    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'isbn_no','book_title');
    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
                   array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
}
```

....
my table will be like below named Books
book_id(PK)   |   isbn_no  |   book_title |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can see in your code is that

IN YOUR CONTROLLER

```
$data=Books::model()->findAll('book_id=:book_id', 
              array(':book_id'=> $_POST['current-Controller']['book_id']));
```

while you should compare isbn_no as you are sending isbn_no from the form to controller...

```
$data=Books::model()->findAll('isbn_no=:isbn_no', 
              array(':isbn_no'=> $_POST['current-Controller']['isbn_no']));
```

If some other error is showing then please mention..as the code seems alright...and you have not mentioned what is the error..

Comment: hi,  i got the error like this ....invalid argument supplied for foreach()   in  view file code below.... <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'book_title','',array(),array('empty'=>'select'));?>